# Serialize different members for XML and JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a couple of classes that I serialize to XML with `DataContract` / `DataMember` attributes and the `DataContractSerializer`.
Now I would like to use the same classes to serialize to JSON for ajax calls from the client.
However the members that I want to serialize to JSON are slightly different from the ones that I want to serialize to XML. Is there a way (with attributes) to differentiate between these two?

BTW I'm using `DataContractSerializer` as opposed to `XmlSerializer` because I need to serialize private members, so switching to `XmlSerializer` is not an option.

Comment: If you want to expose different members in two different contexts, then by definition you have two different data contracts.

Comment: That's true, so I guess the question is can I define two different data contracts on the same class?

Answer (score 1):

For serializing json, I use:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
```

You could also use it for your situation using the ignore attributes to manipulate the output.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

Edit:

Just noticed there was another option which you might be more familiar with in dealing with datacontracts:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer
```

Refersnces:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Comment: Mainly I will need to exclude/ignore members for the XML serialization. Is that possible as well?

Comment: You can ignore public properties of a class with attributes, just link you do with DataContractSerializer. Private members might be a problem. But this serializer will not do XML serializtion. You would need to use DataContractSerializer or XmlSerializer as you mentioned. Check out the link which has an example of the ScriptIgnoreAttribute.